# Archlinux ARM7 3.14.44-1 + wifi dongle R8188EU not working

Tags: wifi, arch-arm

I'm struggiling to get my TPLINK wifi dongle work in Archlinux ARM64.

I start with netctl start tplink, which tplink being:

```
Description='A simple WPA encrypted wireless connection'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless

Security=wpa
IP=dhcp

ESSID='wifi_name_here'
# Prepend hexadecimal keys with \"
# If your key starts with ", write it as '""<key>"'
# See also: the section on special quoting rules in netctl.profile(5)
Key='password'
# Uncomment this if your ssid is hidden
#Hidden=yes
# Set a priority for automatic profile selection
#Priority=10
```

And i get:

```
[root@KRAKEN netctl] systemctl status netctl@tplink.service -l
* netctl@tplink.service - Networking for netctl profile tplink
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-06-17 20:35:19 ART; 8s ago
     Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
  Process: 12545 ExecStart=/usr/lib/network/network start %I (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12545 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: Starting network profile 'tplink'...
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN network[12545]: WPA association/authentication failed for interface 'wlan0'
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN network[12545]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'tplink'
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN systemd[1]: netctl@tplink.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile tplink.
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN systemd[1]: Unit netctl@tplink.service entered failed state.
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN systemd[1]: netctl@tplink.service failed.
```

And in the journal:

```
[root@KRAKEN netctl] journalctl -xe
-- 
-- Unit netctl@tplink.service has begun starting up.
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: Starting network profile 'tplink'...
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
Jun 17 20:34:54 KRAKEN network[12545]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
Jun 17 20:34:56 KRAKEN kernel: R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
Jun 17 20:34:56 KRAKEN kernel: R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
Jun 17 20:34:57 KRAKEN kernel: R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
Jun 17 20:34:59 KRAKEN kernel: R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
Jun 17 20:35:00 KRAKEN kernel: R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
Jun 17 20:35:14 KRAKEN kernel: R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN network[12545]: WPA association/authentication failed for interface 'wlan0'
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN kernel: R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN network[12545]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'tplink'
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN systemd[1]: netctl@tplink.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 17 20:35:19 KRAKEN systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile tplink.
```

What can it be?

Thanks!

Comment: to people visting: realtek leaves much to desire. Avoid buying this stick https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Answer (score 1):

The DKMS package 8188EUS used old drivers.

Ended up compilig this branch:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/tree/v4.1.8_9499

And worked.